# Display specific arrays

Tags: arrays, smarty

I'm new to smarty and I want to display all the arrays that contains `'sezoniere' => null` I have a loop

`{foreach from=$servList item=_item name=servList}`

```
<h6><a href="{$baseURL}{if !$smarty.foreach.servList.first}{$_item.post_name}{else}servicii{/if}/" title="{$_item.nume}">{$_item.nume}</a></h6>
{/foreach}
```

Here is the array:

```
'id' => string '1' (length=1)
'nume' => string 'Serviciul 1' (length=11)
'post_name' => string 'serviciul-1' (length=11)
'sezoniere' => string '1' (length=1)
```

The second array in the loop:

```
'id' => string '2' (length=1)
'nume' => string 'Serviciul 2' (length=11)
'post_name' => string 'serviciul-2' (length=11)
'sezoniere' => null
```

How I can display in the loop above only the array's that have `'sezoniere' => null` ?

Comment: No ideas on how to do this ? Any help pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is:

```
{foreach from=$servList item=_item name=servList}
{if !$_item.sezoniere}{* do nothing *}{else}
<h6 class="orange">{$_item.nume}</h6>
<p class="p0">{$_item.descriere|truncate:300}</p>
<a class="link-1" href="{$baseURL}{if $_item@first}servicii{else}{$_item.post_name}{/if}/" title="{$_item.nume}">Read more</a>
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add if statemant

```
{foreach $servList a $item}
    {if !$item.sezoniere}
       your code here
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

But better solution is defined 2 array in php and declared to smarty.